# Error class not registered, dll not registerable

Tags: c#, exception, dll, com

I'm just trying to set up an older project and while I try to run it I run into a "Class not registered" error

[image: shown error]

Now I've already tried registering the dll that it's referencing, but I could not do it with regsvr32.

[image: regsvr32 error]

I've also tried removing and adding the reference again, but no luck it just keeps happening.

Comment: My personal first impression is that your question is not providing enough informations. About more or less everything. What does `regsrv32` say about this Dll? Are you sure it's a COM Dll? (...)

Comment: @Jimi I'm not even sure it is a COM dll

Comment: Please don't post exception messages as images. Post them as text! By posting images, you prevent others from finding this question and its solution (if they will encounter the same issue).

Comment: That component is part of an ancient EastmanKodak OCX series of controls,  `ImageAdmin.ocx` in specific, IMO. See what it was used for and find a suitable substitute. Probably a `PictureBox` would do the same.

Comment: Or, maybe, it was providing informations on loaded Bitmaps? In that case, you could use the Bitmap/BitmapSource/BitmapDecoder classes.

Comment: If this AxAdminLibCtl.dll doesn't have a DllRegisterServer, it means it's not a COM dll itself. But it probably depends on other binaries. You must find these other binaries and register them